# Inferences with time stamped steps

Tags: logic

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

[image]

What would be the proper way of achieving the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `tabular`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  11:15: & Now(11:15), Meet(B,Lunch,12:00), \\
         & Now(11:15am) $\to$ Go(Lunch) \\
  \cline{2-2}
  11:16: & \textbf{Now(11:16)}, Meet(B,Lunch,12:00), \\
         & Now(11:15am) $\to$ Go(Lunch) \\
  \cline{2-2}
  \dots: & \dots \\
  \cline{2-2}
  \cline{2-2}
  11:45: & \textbf{Now(11:45)}, Meet(B,Lunch,12:00), \\
         & Now(11:15am) $\to$ Go(Lunch) \\
  \cline{2-2}
  11:46: & \textbf{Now(11:46)}, Meet(B,Lunch,12:00), \\
         & Now(11:15am) $\to$ Go(Lunch), \textbf{Go(Lunch)} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with `bussproof`. It is not straigtforward but here is what I optained:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}

\alwaysNoLine
\AxiomC{Now(11:15), Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
\LeftLabel{11:15}
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch)}
\alwaysSingleLine
    \UnaryInfC{Now(11:16),Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
    \LeftLabel{11:16}
    \alwaysNoLine
    \UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch)}
    \alwaysSingleLine
        \UnaryInfC{}
        \alwaysNoLine
        \UnaryInfC{$\cdots$}
        \UnaryInfC{}
        \alwaysSingleLine
            \UnaryInfC{Now(11:45),Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
            \LeftLabel{11:45}
            \alwaysNoLine
            \UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch)}
            \alwaysSingleLine
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:46),Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
\LeftLabel{11:46}
\alwaysNoLine
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch), Go(Lunch)}

\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image: With Bussproof]
I don't know if that's useful, but you can get this too:
[image: Example 2]
with :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{prooftree}
\alwaysNoLine
\AxiomC{Now(11:15), Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
\LeftLabel{11:15}
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch)}
\AxiomC{Now(11:16),Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
\LeftLabel{11:16}
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch)}
\AxiomC{$\cdots$}
\AxiomC{Now(11:45),Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
\LeftLabel{11:45}
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch)}
\alwaysSingleLine
\QuaternaryInfC{Now(11:46),Meet(B,Lunch,12:00),}
\LeftLabel{11:46}
\alwaysNoLine
\UnaryInfC{Now(11:45am)$\rightarrow$Go(Lunch), Go(Lunch)}
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The site [logicmatters](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/) lists packages you can use in LaTeX for logic.